# Scraping Wikipedia table, what am I missing? (Pandas / Beautiful Soup)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape city population numbers from the German language Wikipedia site.

With this code, I don't just get the number, but also the series info `Name: Deutschlandkarte, dtype: object`. What am I missing?

Also, any other hints on how to do it more elegantly very much appreciated. My aim is to enter a list of city names to get their population numbers.

```
import pandas as pd 
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

cityname = "Bonn"
url="https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/"
wikiurl = url+cityname
# table import
table_class="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter"
response=requests.get(wikiurl)
print(response.status_code)
# <table class="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter" style="width:100%; text-align:center;">

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
citytable=soup.find('table',{'id':"Vorlage_Infobox_Verwaltungseinheit_in_Deutschland"})
df=pd.read_html(str(citytable))
# convert list to dataframe
df=pd.DataFrame(df[0])
population = df[(df.iloc[:, 0] == "Einwohner:")].iloc[:, 1].str.split(n = 1).str[0].astype(str).replace('\.', '', regex=True)

data = [       
        [cityname, population] 
       ]
data
# Create the pandas DataFrame 
overview = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Stadt', 'Einwohner']) 
overview
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `item()` to the `population` line. The defined `population` is a series and you desire only a single item from it. That is:

```
population = df[(df.iloc[:, 0] == "Einwohner:")].iloc[:, 1].str.split(n = 1).str[0].astype(str).replace('\.', '', regex=True).item()
```

By inspection you can see it:

```
population = df[(df.iloc[:, 0] == "Einwohner:")].iloc[:, 1].str.split(n = 1).str[0].astype(str).replace('\.', '', regex=True)
print(population,'\n')
print(type(population),'\n\n')

print(population.item(),'\n')
print(type(population.item()))
```

Displays:

```
7    329673
Name: Deutschlandkarte, dtype: object 

<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> 


329673 

<class 'str'>
```

And if you desire `329673` as a number you have to convert it, because it is a string.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert code to a function that takes city as input and returns city and population in a list. You can append these to a master list you then later convert to a dataframe. The population figure can be retrieved by targeting the `td` containing `Einwohner:`, and then moving to the adjacent sibling `td`. Using `stripped_strings` and index 0, one can return just the population stat.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd

def get_city_population_size(city):
    r = s.get(f'https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/{city}')
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml') #html.parser
    population = [s for s in soup.select_one('td:contains("Einwohner:") + td').stripped_strings][0]
    return [city, population]

results = []

with requests.Session() as s:
    for city in ['bonn', 'München']:
        results.append(get_city_population_size(city))
    
df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = ['Stadt', 'Einwohner'])
print(df)
```

Comment: Great. I got an error message, though, so I did it like this:
`_s = requests.session()
    r = s.get(f'https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/{city}')
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml') #html.parser
    population = [s for s in soup.select_one('td:-soup-contains("Einwohner:") + td').stripped_strings][0]
    return [city, population]

results = []`

Comment: what was the error message? Runs fine for me,

Comment: `NameError: name 's' is not defined`

Comment: Not sure how I deleted that line. Sorry. Added it back in.